# How to connect dryer duct to wall?

Tags: dryer, ducts

I just removed a stove and fan, and am left with this rectangular exit for the fan exhaust.

I would like to hook up a dryer in place, and am wondering the best way to connect the round duct from the dryer to the rectangular wall opening.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the rectangle is a 10" x 3-1/4" and the dryer is 4" round, you can get something custom made ($$$) or do this with two pieces;

[rectangle to round](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Broan-3-1-4-in-x-10-in-Rectangular-to-6-in-Round-Galvanized-Steel-Duct-Transition-411/202913013):
[image]

[round 6" to 4"](https://www.homedepot.com/p/6-in-to-4-in-Round-Reducer-R6X4/100111736)
[image]